# System Boot Order not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 through a USB pen drive. I had Windows 7 prior to installation of Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu Installation did not complete successfully. Gave error while installing GRUB and installation failed. I tried by running **Boot Repair Tool.** It completed by showing **Boot Repair completed successfully.** Still I am getting the same error while booting that " System Boot Order not found". After sometime Ubuntu is loaded. But I am not able to access Windows 7. **Mine is Legacy BIOS.**
How to fix this error?

Comment: Please run the command `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` in a terminal window (maybe booted 'live' from the USB pendrive with the installer) and edit your original question to show the output from the command. Please render the output as 'code' in order to make it easier to read. That output will make it easier for us to understand what you have. (We may ask for more details about the computer later if necessary to give you good help.)

Answer (score 0):

from a terminal window in your ubuntu do "sudo update-grub".

It should be able to find your windows 7 installation.

After that  you should be able to see a grub menu on boot with both Ubuntu and Windows 7 options.